# confused with Navigating a LinkedList or keep track the previous elements in LL

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to work on implementation of LinkedList and its very new subject for me.
While working on different type of LinkedList problem, I am facing a general error to traverse the LinkedList such that to keep track the previous elements.
Some fashioned traversing way is

> List L = L.next

and here comes the issue.
Like I want to skip some elements in a List and then delete next set of elements and then again skip Problem.
To do that  I thought of travering the LL till the point to skip , now traverse lead me to think about L = L.next , and then again I am trapped in recursion.

Please explain me a bit about featuring this issue and how to handle this situation.
Kindly consider it as a blockhead in my understanding and thereby I am not able to move further, just a little light will lead me to sort the issue.

*I am very new this kind of implementation*

My LinkedList-

```
        MyList list_Sort = new MyList(9);
        list_Sort.next = new MyList(8);
        list_Sort.next.next = new MyList(8);
        list_Sort.next.next.next = new MyList(7);
        list_Sort.next.next.next.next = new MyList(5);
        list_Sort.next.next.next.next.next = new MyList(4);
        list_Sort.next.next.next.next.next.next = new MyList(6);
        list_Sort.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new MyList(3);
        list_Sort.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new MyList(1);
        list_Sort.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new MyList(2);

9-->8-->8-->7-->5-->4-->6-->3-->1-->2-->TAIL
```

Comment: If you step through your code in your debugger you should be able to see why you have endless recursion. In short; if you have a bug in your code, try the debugger first.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!! That is certainly not the way to traverse a `LinkList`. If you had `10000` nodes you cannot write `.next` `9999` times :-)

Try not to use recursion as far as possible is you are not sure about it. Loops are more easy to use. use a loop:

```
while(current.next != null)
{
    //do your stuff
    current = current.next;
}
```

And if I remember right, you once asked about how to sort `0s and 1s`. You do the same thing you did there. You use pointers to keep track of your nodes. Just traverse to that node which is just before the node you want to delete (using `current` pointer). Then place a pointer there for reference. Then continue traversing (using `present` pointer) till the node you want to delete. Now just go one more hop in the front so that you are exactly pointing to the next node of the one you want to delete. Now do:

```
current.next = present;
```

Vola!! its done

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse to the first element that you don't want to skip via the following logic

```
List tmp = L;
while (tmp != null && doSkip(tmp.data)) {
  tmp = tmp.next;
}
```

Then you go to the first element following that you don't want to delete:

```
List tmp2 = tmp;
while (tmp2 != null && doDelete(tmp2.data)) {
  tmp2 = tmp2.next;
}
```

Then delete the elements between `tmp` and `tmp2` by linking the next from `tmp` to the fist no-delete element:

```
tmp.next = tmp2;
```

Here `doSkip()` and `doDelete()` evaluates whether you want to skip or delete the element respectively.  You might need to keep some state if the logic involves evaluating a sequence.

This approach uses an iterative traversal (not recursive), which I think suits the problem better